# Como descobrir qual o caminho seguido por uma função em js

Tags: javascript

Explicando meu cenário, utilizo emberjs, e ele encapsula cada `Component` dentro de um `Controller` que vai ser encapsulado dentro de um `Router`, e ainda possui um esquema de `Model`, `Mixins`, `Helpers`, isso quando não existe um componente, ou addon, ou mixin conversando com outro componente, addon, mixin (<s>bem vindo ao javascript moderno</s>).... As vezes fica bem difícil de debugar o código, saber o caminho da rota do javascript, o escopo em que tal função ou método foi chamado, usando o `console.debug();` eu consigo pegar o escopo atual da função, mas fica difícil saber aonde aquela função foi chamada. Existe algum método ou modo em javascript de descobrir todo o caminho que a função percorreu até chegar em determinado ponto?

Exemplificando:

```js
function A(){
  B();
}

function B(){
  a.teste();
}

function C(){
  /*Descobrir como o javascript chegou até aqui*/
  console.log("Hellor Weird World!");
  console.debug();
}

var a = {
  teste: function(){
    C();
  }
}

A();
```

Comment: Isso seria muito util, eu faço via inspetor de elementos, claro que ele já tem que estar aberto antes da função executar, mas o grande problema é quando usam `.call` ou `.apply`, como jQuery faz, ai fica quase impossivel encontrar :/ (sei lá porque)

Comment: Uma forma estranha, mas que funciona é `console.log(new Error().stack);`, que é basicamente o sugerido [nesta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/635852/6087092)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe sim um modo de descobrir quem chamou a função, através da variável local `arguments`. Vale ressaltar que esse método somente funciona se você não estiver usando **strict mode**, ou seja, o arquivo não pode conter `'use strict';`

Exemplo:

```
function Hello()
{
    alert("O nome da função que chamou é " + arguments.callee.caller.name);
}

function Main() {
    Hello();
}

Main();
```

Essa execução irá mostrar no alert *"O nome da função que chamou é Main"*.

Porém, você precisa rastrear o caminho completo e não somente o último "caller". Nesse caso teríamos que recursivamente captar os callers, até que sejam nulos. A lógica seria algo similar a isso:

```
function Hello()
{
    rastrear();
}

function Main() {
    Hello();
}

function Main2() {
    Main();
}

function rastrear() {
    var trace = '';
    var haveTrace = true;

    var caller = arguments.callee.caller;

    trace = caller.name + ' -> ';

    while(haveTrace) {
        if(caller.caller) {
            trace = caller.caller.name + ' -> ' + trace;
            caller = caller.caller;
        } else {
            haveTrace = false;
        }
    }

    console.log(trace);
}

Main2();
```

Isso irá imprimir no console o resultado *"Main2 -> Main -> Hello -> "*. **Mas atenção! Utilizar essa função em funções recursivas pode causar um looping infinito!**

---

Uma outra ótima opção seria usar a função `console.trace();`. Nesse caso seria algo assim:

```
function Hello()
{
    console.trace();
}

function Main() {
    Hello();
}

function Main2() {
    Main();
}

Main2();
```

Isso irá resultar em algo assim no console:

```
console.trace
Hello @ VM197:3
Main @ VM197:7
Main2 @ VM197:11
```

Além disso ainda existem outras possibilidades programáveis, mas já é um ótimo ponto de partida.

Comment: para usar o rastrear() eu iria ter que declarar a função dentro do meu sistema, correto? Será que funcionaria bem com múltiplos arquivos js que conversam entre si em um mesmo projeto? Achei bacana o `console.trace()`! Não conhecia =)

Comment: Funciona sim. Porém no seu caso, em um framework, muita coisa acontece por trás dos panos. Pode ser que ele acabe "rastreando", execuções de funções de classes ancestrais como `Controller`, `Component`, `Router` e etc... tem esse fator. Sobre o `console.trace()`, realmente é uma ótima opção, e eventualmente deve cair na situação que citei do rastreamento também.